# AngularJS + Materialize dropdown doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, materialize, dropdown

I have a problem...
My Materialize dropdown works only after a reloading of my homepage.
I tried all the solutions which I was able to find. Nothing can be done.

Here is my code :

```js
this.$postLink = () => {
      $timeout(() => {
        $('.dropdown-button').dropdown();
      }, 1000);
    };
```

```html
<li ng-if="$ctrl.parent.isLogged()">
    <a class="dropdown-button" href data-activates="menu_user">
       {{'NAVBAR.HELLO' | translate}} {{$ctrl.parent.userName()}}
           <i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i>
    </a>
</li>
```

Thanks for your help ;) !

Comment: Have you injected $timeout into your controller? any errors?

Comment: Thanks Joe ! Yes, $timeout is injected into my controller

Comment: Why dont you use angular-materialize?

Comment: Hummm... Good question. But I see bad migrating to another framework. Unless I can use both. What do you think about it?

Comment: Materialize isnt a framework, its a library. You should use AngularJS supported libraries if you don't want to write a directive for every element binding you need.

Comment: I am going to try to use to angular material before using the directive. Thank you again once to you two!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <a class='dropdown-button btn' 
     href='#' 
     data-activates='dropdown1' 
     my-dropdown-button>Drop Me!</a>

  <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
    <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function() {});

myApp.directive('myDropdownButton', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      element.dropdown({
        inDuration: 300,
        outDuration: 225,
        constrainWidth: false, // Does not change width of dropdown to that of the activator
        hover: true, // Activate on hover
        gutter: 0, // Spacing from edge
        belowOrigin: false, // Displays dropdown below the button
        alignment: 'left', // Displays dropdown with edge aligned to the left of button
        stopPropagation: false // Stops event propagation
      });
    }
  }
});
```

**> [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qme4qLvL/)**

Comment: Thanks lin ! I'll try this !